# How to allow multiple '--insecure-registry' for docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

As we all known, we can add one `--insecure-registry` to the `/etc/default/docker` config file to allow insecure registry, like this:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --insecure-registry myregistry:5000"
```

My question is: Does it support adding more than one `--insecure-registry` since we need to communicate with more than one registries ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can specify multiple insecure registries by lining them up:

```
--insecure-registry IP1:PORT --insecure-registry IP2:PORT --insecure-registry IP3:PORT
```

Source: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9026

Comment: Is there a way to tell docker to allow any insecure registry without having to enumerate each one?

Comment: @frakman1 This parameter accepts CIDR notation as well, so "--insecure-registry 0.0.0.0/1 --insecure-registry 128.0.0.0/1" should cover it. For obvious reasons, this is not recommended. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#insecure-registries for more information to insecure registries.

Answer (score 10):

## Docker 17.xx +

1. Edit the `daemon.json` file, whose default location is `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on Linux or `C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json` on Windows Server

   > If the `daemon.json` file does not exist, create it.

   ```
   {
         "insecure-registries": ["myregistry:5000", "anotherregistry:5000"]
   }
   ```
2. Restart Docker for the changes to take effect. In Ubuntu would be like this:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   $ sudo systemctl restart docker
   ```

Find more details in official documentation page https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker on RHEL,CentOS,Fedora etc

(you can configure the same in Ubuntu but it's int another location)

you can add the next line in the docker service
/etc/sysconfig/docker

```
INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry IP1:PORT1 --insecure-registry IP2:PORT2'
```

save the file
and restart the docker

```
$ systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

update following lines in `/etc/containers/registries.conf`

```
# Registries that do not use TLS when pulling images or uses self-signed
# certificates.
[registries.insecure]
registries = ['myregistry:5000','myregistry2:5000']
```

and restart sevice

`systemctl restart docker`